# Excel Highlight differences in rows based on matching columns

Tags: excel, vlookup, highlight

I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets, Sheet 1 is last years data, Sheet 2 is this years data. I need to compare data in Sheet 1 Column A to Sheet 2 Column A. If the data matches in Column A in both sheets, I need to compare and highlight the differences in those rows where they matched up. I have only been able to highlight the differences in the columns not the rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a row by row comparison? or can the data be the same in different rows?

Comment: How are you planning to compare the values? Going back and forth between sheets, or maybe create a 3rd sheet? Are there a lot of columns? Will Column A ever have the same value repeated? I think mock-up data would help here.

Comment: • This is a row by row comparison
• I was hoping to highlight the fields that cells that do not match, so not having to go back and forth or create a 3rd sheet. Column A will not have the same value repeated. There is a total of 10 columns, Column A being unique to each row.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of if Column A matches in both sheets, compare values in Column D, E, F, G for that row. If they are different highlight that cell.

Comment: Maybe share an image of what your layout is looking like

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out I compared the columns and then compared the cells in those rows to the second sheet